# Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-plugins

I'm using `Phonegap` framework. All the **js files** are loaded completely.
I'm using the following statement.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "MyDB.db" });
```

but I'm getting error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide some code snippets to indicate the context in which your statement is executed. If you think that all the JS files are loaded completely, then may be you're trying to execute this statement even before your `sqlitePlugin` is initialized and added to window scope.

Answer (score 1):

There are some points which need to be known:

- database activity can only be done when the `onDeviceReady()` method has fired
- For this I’m going to open the database in the `modules .run()` method like:

  ```
  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
  ```

Before writing this line , make sure that you have added **SQLite plugin** and `$cordovaSQLite` dependency is added in your project .

Here is an example:

```
var db = null;
var example = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])



.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
    });
});
```

Hope this will work for you. For reference you can use [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/):

Answer (score -1):

Your TypeError answeres your Question pretty good ;)

He cant execute the fucntion 'openDatabase()' because ur window.sqlitePlugin is not defined at this point.

Send us some code or make sure ur Plugin is reachable at this point of execution.

I suggest u use a Debugger Chrom -> F12
There u can figure out pretty quick where ur Problem is :)

F12 -> ESC 
(Bottom section u can choose "Console", Top section u select "Sources" and navigate to ur file)
Breakpoint -> go for it :)